# jquery click event working multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to find each target element in iframe on click event. But the click event triggers mutiple times on each click. This is the code that i used. I am using this function to style each target element on click. How can i solve this issue.

```
 var getElement = function () {
     $('[data-edit="froala"]').on('froalaEditor.initialized', function (e, editor) {
        var $div_tag = $('[data-edit="froala"]').find('iframe').contents().find('body');
            $div_tag.on('click', function(e) {
                var element_name = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                var $target_class = $('[data-target="'+element_name+'"]');
                trigger_object(e);
        });
     });
 }

 var trigger_object = function (e) {
   $('body').on('change', '[data-style="hr-style"]', function (event) {
       $(e.target).css($(this).data('css'),this.value);
   });
   $('body').on('change', '[data-style="div-style"]', function (event) {
       $(e.target).css($(this).data('css'),this.value);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Can you also add your html code? What is froala, and when do you trigger foalaEditor.initialized?

Comment: Check how often your `froalaEditor.initialized` is fired. You add every round an new click handler of `$div_tag`.

Comment: froala is a inline editor editor and froalaEditor.initialized is used to check froala is loaded

Comment: You are missing a `.` after `find('iframe')`, maybe a typo...

Comment: @pleinx thanks for the reply. Actually froalaEditor.initialized is working only once. Actually the issue happened due to the wrong way that i handle the target element. The issue is that when i click one  div element in iframe i got the div target object and its wrking fine. Then i click on another div i got previos click div and current div object and its come like a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unbind your existing change event before binding it to prevent event from working multiple times

add .off('change') to unbind all exiting change event
before .on('change') to bind the change event

```
$('[data-style="hr-style"]').off('change').on('change', function (event) {
   $(e.target).css($(this).data('css'),this.value);
});
$('[data-style="div-style"]').off('change').on('change', function (event) {
   $(e.target).css($(this).data('css'),this.value);
});
```

Comment: When i using the off event, its not working for [data-style="hr-style"] change method. Only second [data-style="div-style"] change method working. If I comment second [data-style="div-style"] change method, then first [data-style="hr-style"] change method working fine

Comment: Now its working fine. But is off method is a good way?. How can i do prevent multiple times in my code

Comment: .off() function is the best way to do that it unbind existing events from your element and prevent event working multiple times

Comment: its working fine when using $('[data-style="hr-style"]').off('change').on('change', function (event) {

Comment: @YeldhoPaul ah. I see my previous code only unbind the change event of body instead of [data-style="hr-style"] and [data-style="div-style"]

Comment: Actuallly why its happens multiple times. is it possible to avoid multiple times in getElement function

Comment: @YeldhoPaul everytime your div tag is click the function trigger_object called which bind the change events into your elements and that happens every time you click the div tag that's why unbind() must be use for this to prevent your element events from running multiple times

Comment: Ok. Thanks for sharing your valuable time with me

Answer (score 0):

Then probably foralaEditor.initialized is fired multiple times.
Try with off, but on the *div_tag* click not on *body*,

```
var getElement = function () {
     $('[data-edit="froala"]').on('froalaEditor.initialized', function (e, editor) {
        var $div_tag = $('[data-edit="froala"]').find('iframe')contents().find('body');
            $div_tag.off('click').on('click', function(e) {
                var element_name = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                var $target_class = $('[data-target="'+element_name+'"]');
                trigger_object(e);
        });
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its not working. The change method inside trigger_object is working multiple times on each click in element in iframe. How can i solve this issue

Comment: @YeldhoPaul please add html code (where you use data-target) to your question.